# Help with rectangle splitting in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw something like the following picture. I tried the split tikz library, and tried splitting a rectangle but drawing 32 parts is not happening, it is showing only some parts.

Any help on how can I draw the picture in latex.

Thank you.[image: picture]

Comment: It is not difficult to draw that figure. What is it about?

Comment: It is about memory bits actually, as per the colour the bits will be used in the next round. It will be of great help if you kindly help me out with the picture @BlackMild

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is simple example using a `\pic` for the rectangles and numbered colors to make the code brief.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

% colors
\definecolor{color0}{HTML}{999999} % gray
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{FF0000} % red
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{0000FF} % blue
\definecolor{color3}{HTML}{00FF00} % green
\definecolor{color4}{HTML}{FF9999} % light red
 
\tikzset
{
  pics/my rectangle/.style={% #1 -> list of numbers (colors)
    code={%
      \foreach[count=\j]\i in {#1}
        \fill[color\i] (0.2*\j,0) rectangle (0.2*\j+0.18,0.5); 
      \coordinate (-label) at (3.39,-0.3);
      }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic  (A) at (0,0) {my rectangle={0,0,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
  \node at (A-label) {$0-31$};
  \pic  (B) at (8,0) {my rectangle={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
  \node at (B-label) {$32-63$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your B-label has an off-by-one error :-)

Comment: @Thruston, yep, you are right. Thanks for the correction!!!

Comment: Thank you for your time @JuanCastano

Comment: Any comments on having the color meaning as caption as  "red rectangle slice: active bits, "blue rectangle slice: inactive bits,..." ? I tried using tikzpicture in \caption{}, but it is showing me error !

Answer (score 5):

Or you could try [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
color key[];
key0 = 5/8 white;
key1 = Reds 8 6;
key2 = Oranges 8 6;
key3 = Greens 8 6;
key4 = Blues 8 6;

beginfig(1);
numeric x, y, h; x = y = h = 0;
forsuffixes $=0,0,2,2,2,4,4,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,2,2,0,0,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,0,0,2,2,4,0,2,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4, 0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,
              1,2,4,0,0,0,0,1, 2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,2,4,4,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
              2,1,2,4,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,2,2,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1:

    fill unitsquare xscaled 3 yscaled 16 shifted (4x + 32h, -42y) withcolor key$;
    x := x + 1;
    if x = 32:
        h := 1;
    elseif x = 64:
        x := 0; h := 0; y := y + 1;
    fi
    if x = 16:
        label.bot(decimal 64y & "–" & decimal (64y + 31), (4x, -42y));
    elseif x = 48:
        label.bot(decimal (64y + 32) & "–" & decimal (64y + 63), (4x + 32, -42y));
    fi
endfor

interim bboxmargin := 16;
draw bbox currentpicture withpen pencircle scaled 1;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

And with a legend...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
color key[];
key0 = 5/8 white;
key1 = Reds 8 6;
key2 = Oranges 8 6;
key3 = Greens 8 6;
key4 = Blues 8 6;

string desc[];
desc0 = "Grey $\pi$"; % thanks to the "textextlabel" option above this is processed through TEX()
desc1 = "Red";
desc2 = "Orange";
desc3 = "Green";
desc4 = "Blue";

beginfig(1);
numeric x, y, h; x = y = h = 0;
forsuffixes $=0,0,2,2,2,4,4,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,2,2,0,0,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,0,0,2,2,4,0,2,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4, 0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,
              1,2,4,0,0,0,0,1, 2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1, 2,0,0,2,4,4,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
              2,1,2,4,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,2,2,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1:

    fill unitsquare xscaled 3 yscaled 16 shifted (4x + 32h, -42y) withcolor key$;
    x := x + 1;
    if x = 32:
        h := 1;
    elseif x = 64:
        x := 0; h := 0; y := y + 1;
    fi
    if x = 16:
        label.bot(decimal 64y & "–" & decimal (64y + 31), (4x, -42y));
    elseif x = 48:
        label.bot(decimal (64y + 32) & "–" & decimal (64y + 63), (4x + 32, -42y));
    fi
endfor

%
% make a legend
picture legend; legend = image(
    for i = 0 upto 4:
        fill unitsquare xscaled -3 yscaled 12 shifted (50i, -6) withcolor key[i];
        label.rt(desc[i], (50i, 0));
    endfor
);
label.bot(legend, point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture shifted 13 down);

interim bboxmargin := 16;
draw bbox currentpicture withpen pencircle scaled 1;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative ways are always good to know. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

An alternative construction with `matrix` and `.list` to collor inner cells.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit}

\colorlet{color0}{gray}
\colorlet{color1}{red}
\colorlet{color2}{blue}
\colorlet{color3}{green}
\colorlet{color4}{pink}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, inner sep=0mm,
        nodes={fill=color0, anchor=center, minimum width=2mm, 
                minimum height=5mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
        column sep=.25mm,
        },
    col1/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={fill=color1}}},      
    col2/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={fill=color2}}},        
    col3/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={fill=color3}}},      
    col4/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={fill=color4}}},        
    ]
    
\matrix[mymatrix, col4/.list={3,4,5}, col2/.list={6,7}, label=below:0-31] (A1)
    {&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\};
\matrix[mymatrix, col3/.list={8}, col1/.list={16}, col4/.list={17}, label=below:32-63, right=1cm of A1] (A2)
    {&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\};
\matrix[mymatrix, col1/.list={2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14}, col2/.list={7,8,25,16,23}, color3/.list={15,29,32}, label=below:64-95, below=1cm of A1] (A3)
    {&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\};
\matrix[mymatrix, col1/.list={1,8,16,24,32}, col2/.list={5,12,16,20,28}, label=below:96-127, below=1cm of A2] (A4)
    {&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\};
\node[fit=(A1) (A4), inner sep=5mm, draw, line width=1mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]